# is it possible to break I/O blocking with a bad CD/DVD (read errors) in windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, io

I find it very frustrating when I insert a CD that has read errors on it and windows freezes up for a long time. What is the fastest way to break this blocking? I usually kill explorer.exe and restart it, but in windows 7 even this does not always help!

Comment: I can't think of a better solution without writing new drivers. . .

Answer (score 1):

Manually eject the disc by pushing the eject button on the drive tray.

I have noticed this behavior in W7 and how it handles dirty or damaged discs, it goes nuts sometimes trying to read the disc, what I do is Use [Ultra ISO](http://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/) to read or copy data from the disc if I know it is damaged, it seems to manage the errors much better.

Comment: sometimes you have to wait for ages before the disc will even be ejected, meanwhile a anything to do with i/o remains unusable

Comment: Check my edit to my post.

Comment: Thanks for the information, this is helpful. I've done that kind of thing in the past with isobuster. actually though I'm trying to find out if it's possible to prevent windows from blocking like this at all

Comment: I have never found a way, let me know if you do.